# verbatimTextOutput Appending Text

Tags: r, shiny

I have a question about how we can append text to the text already displayed text in the verbatimTextOutput. I can save the older text in a variable, keep updating it and then at the display it in the verbatimTextOutput but I want to be able to output messages as they are generated and display in a "running" log.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    actionButton("back", "BACK"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
        output$text <- renderText("Button GO Pressed")
      })

  observeEvent(input$back, {
        output$text <- renderText("Button BACK Pressed")
      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So right now, when I press the buttons, the messages just override each other. For example, if I press "GO", the message "Button GO Pressed" is displayed in the text output field. When I press "BACK" button, the message "Button BACK Pressed" is displayed. HOWEVER, the previous message is overwritten. I want to have a running log essentially, which displays/appends all the messages, hence, showing the running history of button presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to define the running text log as a `reactiveVal`. Check `?reactiveVal` for additional details on how to update a `reactiveVal` inside a reactive expression or observer. Every time one of the action buttons is pressed, you can append a line to the existing text-log inside an `observeEvent`. Here is a small demo of what this might look like:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    actionButton("back", "BACK"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## empty initial log
  textLog <- reactiveVal("")

  observeEvent(input$go, {
        ## add 'Button GO Pressed' to existing log
        textLog(paste(textLog(), "\n Button GO Pressed"))
      })

  observeEvent(input$back, {
        ## add 'Button BACK Pressed' to existing log
        textLog(paste(textLog(), "\n Button BACK Pressed"))
      })

  output$text <- renderText({
        textLog()
      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this does work. I am new to R and shiny, hence did not know about reactiveVal() function. Having said that, could there be an another solution where I read what I printed out in the verbatimTextOutput, append new text to it by using paste and then setting the new output in the box.

Comment: Actually my question is then does anyone know how to read the contents or texts of verbatimTextOutput, save it in a variable and then paste/update.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you mean exactly. Perhaps you could edit the question or create a new one to clarify.

Comment: So my question is, can I read the currently displayed text in the verbatimTextOutput, save it in a variable and paste to that variable additional text?

Comment: @SajjadSyediko: it seems that what you are asking for is already there in the code. The reactive value `textLog()` contains the text currently displayed in the `verbatimTextOutput` by construction, and every time an action button is pressed additional text is appended to the `textLog()` variable.